# Дождь это не помеха. Война это не шутки. Нужно ли здесь тире? Спасибо

Tags: пунктуация

Дождь это не помеха. Война это не шутки. Нужно ли здесь тире? Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

> Нужно ли здесь тире?

НУЖНО. См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106 :

> **§ 11.** Тире ставится перед сказуемым, присоединяемым к подлежащему словами ***вот, это...***